# Clean up TCL list & output

Tags: coding-style, tcl, code-cleanup

Hello I am working on a small script that will allow me to parse information from an input. This is working, but i Know that there is a better way to have done this. Please, I am trying to learn [self taught] so tear me up. The input would be as follows:

```
C7-0-4-U1   36.5 mHz    IN7-0-4-0   567 mHz 00:15:d0:e3:b0:41   online(pt)  10.106.156.129  42.0    -0.5    35.1    -3.0    38.7    0.0E+000    0.0E+000    9   0    12:20:32 AM    rZ5 1       


C7-0-4-U1   36.5 mHz    IN7-0-4-0   567 mHz 2c:9e:5f:de:ed:36   w-online(pt)    10.113.52.11    36.5    0.0 35.1    -5.0    37.7    4.9E-006    0.0E+000    9   0    12:20:32 AM    r4G 0       


C7-0-4-U1   36.5 mHz    IN7-0-4-0   567 mHz e4:83:99:6d:57:ad   w-online(pt)    10.113.45.239   43.5    0.0 35.1    -4.6    39.5    5.8E-006    0.0E+000    8   0    12:20:34 AM    r4G 0       


C7-0-4-U1   36.5 mHz    IN7-0-4-0   567 mHz 3c:75:4a:9c:7b:92   w-online(pt)    10.109.238.61   42.2    -0.5    33.9    -14.4   34.6    4.9E-006    0.0E+000    199 4    12:20:33 AM    rC2 0
```

The Desired Output would be as follows:

00:15:D0:E3:B0:41     10.106.156.129
2C:9E:5F:DE:ED:36     10.113.52.11
E4:83:99:6D:57:AD     10.113.45.239
3C:75:4A:9C:7B:92     10.109.238.61

The Code that I have is as follows:

```
#GET INPUT FROM CLIPBOARD
set Input [sh_set clipboard]
#REMOVE ALL EXCESSIVE WHITESPACE
regsub -all {\s{3,}} $Input "\n" CleanInput
#SET THE INPUT AS LIST
set List [split $CleanInput "\n"]
#GET LIST ITEMS
set Cust1 [lindex $List 1]
set Cust2 [lindex $List 2]
set Cust3 [lindex $List 3]
set Cust4 [lindex $List 4]
regexp -all {(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}([.-:]))(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}\1){4}[[:xdigit:]]{2}} $Cust1 C1MacAddress
regexp -all {10\.(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)} $Cust1 C1IpAddress
regexp -all {(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}([.-:]))(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}\1){4}[[:xdigit:]]{2}} $Cust2 C2MacAddress
regexp -all {10\.(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)} $Cust2 C2IpAddress
regexp -all {(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}([.-:]))(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}\1){4}[[:xdigit:]]{2}} $Cust3 C3MacAddress
regexp -all {10\.(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)} $Cust3 C3IpAddress
regexp -all {(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}([.-:]))(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}\1){4}[[:xdigit:]]{2}} $Cust4 C4MacAddress
regexp -all {10\.(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)} $Cust4 C4IpAddress
return "$C1MacAddress\t$C1IpAddress\n$C2MacAddress\t$C2IpAddress\n$C3MacAddress\t$C3IpAddress\n$C4MacAddress\t$C4IpAddress"
```

Comment: What's the question? awk will help here, TCL seems like an overkill

Comment: Really it is just to get better, I knew that there was a 'foreach' that could have done it in far less lines than I had. I usually can work out how to make something work... I am now working on streamlining my code to make it work efficiently.

Comment: **The reason this is being done in TCL is that I use a program the runs it. I use PcShorthand 10 to automate a lot of repetitious work. The program is really great for those who type a lot.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming that we load it from a txt file, that would be how I'd do it:

```
set input [open "file.txt" r]
set output [open "output.txt" w]
set count 1

while {[gets $input line] != -1} {
    if {$line == ""} {continue} #Skip empty lines
    regexp -all {(\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2})} $line - MacAddress #trap the mac address and store into $MacAddress
    regexp -all {(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $line - IpAddress #trap the IP address and store into $IpAddress
    puts $output "Customer $count: $MacAddress $IpAddress"
    incr count
}

close $input
close $output
```

And I just thought it could be fancy if you could say which customer is which ^^. You can remove the part 'Customer $count' and any lines involving '$count' if you don't need that extra feature.

Or if the input data is in table form (meaning the information you need are in the same columns, I'd go for:

```
set input [open "file.txt" r]
set output [open "output.txt" w]
set count 1

while {[gets $input line] != -1} {
    if {$line == ""} {continue} #Skip empty lines
    regsub -all { +} $line " " newline #trims excess spaces
    set MacAddress [lindex [split $line " "] 6]
    set MIpAddress [lindex [split $line " "] 8]
    puts $output "Customer $count: $MacAddress $IpAddress"
    incr count
}

close $input
close $output
```

Comment: Thank you to all that replied. As stated I am learning TCL and way to know how to better my work.

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution:

```
# read entire file
set fid [open file.txt r]
set txt [read $fid]
close $fid

# split into lines
set lines0 [split $txt \n]

# take only non-empty lines
set lines {}
foreach line $lines0 {
    if {[string trim $line] ne ""} {
        lappend lines $line
    }
}

# extract the required data from each line
foreach line $lines {
    set data [regexp -inline {(\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2})\s+\S+\s+ (\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)} $line]
    foreach {dummy x y} $data {
        puts "$x\t$y"
    }
}
```

The regexp I used search for the pattern of six 2-chars words separated by colons, then a space followed by a word followed by a space (\s+\S+\s+) then the pattern of the ip 
address.

The regexp returns a list of trios (which is flat, not a list of lists) where each trio consists of the entire match, then the first parnthesis match, then the scond one. Hence the dummy var.

Alternatively, you can do withou a regexp, since each line has the same number of words. Since in tcl you can treat a string as alist, whose items are sparated by spaces, you can extract your data more simply by:

```
foreach line $lines {
    set x [lindex $line 6]
    set y [lindex $line 8]
    puts "$x\t$y"
}
```